# Rails 4: Assigning a records "has many" attribute without database saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a couple models shown below and I'm using the search class method in `Thing` to filter records

```
class Category << ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :thing
end

class Thing << ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category

  :scope approved -> { where("approved = true") }

  def self.search(query)
    search_condition = "%" + query + "%"
    approved.where('name LIKE ?', search_condition)
  end
end
```

It works fine in my Things controller. The index route looks like so:

```
def index
   if params[:search].present?
     @things = Thing.search(params[:seach])
   else
     @thing = Thing.all
   end
end
```

On the categories show route I display the Things for this category. I also have the search form to search within the category.

```
def show
  @category = Categories.find(params[:id])

  if params[:search].present?
     @category.things = @category.things.search()
  end
end
```

So the problem is that the `category_id` attribute of all the filtered things are getting set to `nil` when I use the search class method in the `categories#show` route. Why does it save it to database? I thought I would have to call `@category.save` or `update_attribute` for that. I'm still new to rails so I'm sure its something easy I'm overlooking or misread.

My current solution is to move the if statement to the view. But now I'm trying to add pages with kaminiri to it and its getting uglier.

```
<% if params[:search].present? %>
  <% @category.things.search(params[:search]) do |thing| %>
   ... Show the filtered things!
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  <% @category.things do |thing| %>
  ... Show all the things!
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The other solution I thought of was using an `@things = @categories.things.search(params[:search])` but that means I'm duplicated things passed to the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference). A `has_many` association creates a number of methods on the model to which `collection=(objects)` also belongs. According to the guide:

> The collection= method makes the collection contain only the supplied
>   objects, by adding and deleting as appropriate.

In your example you are actually assigning all the `thing`s found using `@category.things.search()` to the `Category` which has previously been queried using `Categories.find(params[:id])`.

Answer (score 0):

Like Yan said, "In your example you are actually assigning all the things found using @category.things.search() to the Category which has previously been queried using Categories.find(params[:id])". Validations will solve this problem.

Records are being saved as nil because you have no validations on your model. Read about active record [validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html). 
Here's the example they provide. You want to validate presence as well because records are being created without values.

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true
end

Person.create(name: "John Doe").valid? # => true
Person.create(name: nil).valid? # => false
```